# can contactor, water level sensor and heater all live in parallel on the same circuit

Tags: sensor, water, level, contactor

I want to connect my 3000w (220v) water heating element to a 220v water level sensor [Automático de Nível](http://www.schneider.ind.br/produtos/acess%C3%B3rios/autom%C3%A1tico-de-n%C3%ADvel/) so that the heating element won't turn on when there is no water present.

But the level sensor can't handle the load (1/2 HP max) so I'm using a contactor.. Can I rig it all up in parallel on the same circuit? Please see below schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft94Af.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but it's not all in parallel.

Here's your drawing edited to make it a little easier to read and with a circuit breaker added.

[image]

Comment: How can I phrase my question correctly? Rather than "all in parallel"  I'm asking if I can run this all with the same phase and neutral feed wires, rather than separate feeds from the circuit breaker for the sensor and heater...

Comment: I've added a circuit breaker to the drawing which should make further verbal explanation unnecessary If I drew it in like it's wired.  You may want to add or explain about the thermostat, though, if there's one in there.